# It's possible to connect a Pressure Sensor to raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, sensors, pressure

It's possible to use a pressure sensor from a car to act like a button in raspberry pi?

Comment: It's rather hard to tell given the lack of any technical detail in your linked product!

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

Just consider your pressure sensor as a regular push-button in the following example. Don't forget the resistor.

https://raspberrypihq.com/use-a-push-button-with-raspberry-pi-gpio/

Comment: Do I need the resistor if I use pull up resistor ?

Comment: The resistor in this example is to limit current in the input. You could use a pull-down resistor as well to preserve the same logic as the example code.